# Devise & CanCan — Issues with CanCan 2.0 API

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise, cancan

I'd like to have additional attributes for my User model and don't want to create a separate Profile model.
I'm trying to update custom fields with standart «update» from RESTful set of actions:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  # ...
  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    authorize! :update, @user
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :ok }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And it all goes fine except the fact that the current_user is able to update any user's profile. It seems I can't restrict any User action. I've tried:

```
can :update, User, :id => user.id
```

and

```
cannot :update, User # at all
```

with no luck. Using Devise 1.5.0 and CanCan 2.0.0.alpha

Here's my ability.rb

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new(:role => nil) # guest user (not logged in)
    can :access, :all
    if user.admin?
      can :manage, :all
    else
      can :read, Review
      if user.customer?
        can :update, User, :id => user.id
        can [:create, :update, :destroy], Review, :user_id => user.id
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code looks good to me.
What if you try to simplify  the second condition first and take out the customer condition? And maybe take out "can :access, :all

Something like:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new(:role => nil) # guest user (not logged in)
    if user.admin?
      can :access, :all
    else
      can :read, :all
      can :update, :users, :id => user.id
      can [:create, :update, :destroy], :reviews, :user_id => user.id
    end
  end
end
```

Does your restriction work for Reviews (that user can only edit his own reviews) ?
I have a similar ability file but I always work with a seperate profile model..

Comment: Yep, for any other models but `User` CanCan works like a charm. I've got more than two user roles and few more resources (I've posted truncated ability.rb).

Comment: Oops, I've lied. Ok, so CanCan 2.0 uses symbols to define resources rather than constants and it seems important. So I've messed up my ability.rb pretty good. It turned out that none of my resource-specific restrictions work. Therefore it must be `can :update, :users, :id => user.id` and so on.

Comment: It turned out that `can :access, :all` also important (I need to get better understanding of difference between `:access` and `:manage`). So you could update  your answer with my symbol stuff and I'll accept it.

Comment: ah okay, interesting. i am still using cancan 1.6.7 with class names. will update answer.