# Securing a HABTM Relationship using Cancan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

`shops habtm products` and vice-versa.

`user has many shops` and `shop belongs to user`

In my `Product=>:create` form, I can check all the shops that a product belongs to using checkboxes (which sends shop_ids as params).

What is the best way to make sure that the user does not create a product and associate it to a shop he does not own in cancan?

It seems like a pretty straightforward use case but I haven't found a good example =(

Currently, I'm doing this.

```
can [:create], Product, do |p|
  (p.shop_ids - user.shop_ids).empty?
end
```

From this, I read it off as `p.shop_ids` must be a complete subset of `user.shop_ids` to get an empty array after the minus operation.

I don't know if I've made any logical flaws or is there a simpler way of checking?

Comment: I would rather make this a validation in the User model.

Comment: Is there a built in way or writing a custom validation? My idea is that it's an action that requires to be `authorized` so that even when a scenario where we save a record via `:validate=>false`, the authorization will still kick in and say you don't have the rights to create this?

Comment: No built in. I do it in the model because I feel it's an integrity constraint. I belive it can also be done in DB. If you skip validation by hand you can also skip authorization by hand.

Comment: Thanks. You reminded me that there should be validation in model as well to watch the data integrity too. I'll try it out =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CanCan 2.0](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/tree/2.0) is good for that.

```
can :create, :products, :shops => { :id => user.shop.id }
```

You may want to give it a try, however it's still in alpha.

P.S. It has major API changes regarding `ability.rb`. Worth attention if you'll decide to try it —> [Devise & CanCan — Issues with CanCan 2.0 API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8442668/devise-cancan-issues-with-cancan-2-0-api)

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try, from the current wiki, pre 2.0?, I see `can :manage, Project, :group => { :id => user.group_ids }`, I wonder if this code is equivalent. From the plural, it doesn't seem so but I'm giving it a try.